# iOS Error on launch from deeplink: lsd[738] <Warning>: LaunchServices: application launch failed - timeout waiting for launch

Tags: ios, deep-linking

When launching my iOS app from a deeplink (a URL with app specific scheme), I get this error in log:

```
lsd[738] <Warning>: LaunchServices: application launch failed - timeout waiting for launch.
```

when the app is launched normally, there is no error.

There is no other log regarding the root of the timeout.
I am looking at the log coming from a device.
Here is the full log:

```
Mar 26 18:03:35 iPod kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[2291] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E1E3A2BC-E5B7-4BE3-881D-CFFC37666FA2 (sandbox)
Mar 26 18:03:35 iPod MobileSafari[2291] <Error>: assertion failed: 12F5047f: libxpc.dylib + 51923 [A76ECB1C-8653-340A-A02D-52E89E8A8902]: 0x7d
Mar 26 18:03:35 iPod Unknown[2291] <Error>: 
Mar 26 18:03:35 iPod locationd[63] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Mar 26 18:03:35 iPod MobileSafari[2291] <Error>: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Mar 26 18:03:36 iPod locationd[63] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Mar 26 18:03:36 iPod backboardd[56] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
Mar 26 18:03:38 iPod kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[2295] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8D14282B-075D-431C-B5BE-D9961FB420D7 (sandbox)
Mar 26 18:03:38 iPod syncdefaultsd[2287] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "ignored" on (null)
Mar 26 18:03:38 iPod locationd[63] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Mar 26 18:03:38 iPod Training[2295] <Error>: assertion failed: 12F5047f: libxpc.dylib + 51923 [A76ECB1C-8653-340A-A02D-52E89E8A8902]: 0x7d
Mar 26 18:03:38 iPod Unknown[2295] <Error>: 
Mar 26 18:03:48 iPod **lsd[738] <Warning>: LaunchServices: application launch failed - timeout waiting for launch.**
Mar 26 18:03:48 iPod Training[2295] <Warning>: willFinishLaunchingWithOptions
Mar 26 18:03:48 iPod Training[2295] <Warning>: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

Comment: What's your appDelegate code for handling the URL scheme?

Comment: it looks like during the timeout no method is being called. in the log, the timeout error is showing up even before the willFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Once the app receives the openURL, everything goes fine: the deeplink URL is handled properly. The main issue is that no method is being called on the app for 10 seconds. and then the warning comes up for the timeout.

Comment: Show your code (or at least the structure) for - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation . If your app is never hitting this method (or only hitting it under certain circumstances), then that tells you something (though more thought might be needed to figure out exactly what...)

Comment: Eric, I'm seeing a similar behavior. Out of curiosity, is your code, or a 3rd party library you're using calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor UUIDString];` during launch?

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing 8 second delays before seeing the same log message.

```
Mar 26 18:03:48 iPod **lsd[738] <Warning>: LaunchServices: application launch failed - timeout waiting for launch.**
```

This was only happening when launching the app when the app was not already in the background. I filed a bug with Apple. This issue is supposedly fixed in iOS 9 beta 4. Unfortunately, older versions of iOS will continue to have this problem.